# How to define a TreeViewItem Triggers in a TreeView user control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I have created TreeView user control that allows multiselection. In order to visually show the selected items I use triggers in a `Style` for `TreeViewItem`. This Style is defined in the user control resources as follows:

```
<TreeView x:Class="SchoolsExample.MultiSelectionTreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SchoolsExample"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="local:MultiSelectionTreeViewItemBehaviour.IsMultiSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(local:MultiSelectionTreeViewItemBehaviour.IsMultiSelected), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelectionActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

But when I want to use this control I want to style my `TreeViewItem`s something like this:

```
    <local:MultiSelectionTreeView x:Name="MultiSelectionTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}">
        <local:MultiSelectionTreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="local:MultiSelectionTreeViewItemBehaviour.IsMultiSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>
        </local:MultiSelectionTreeView.Resources>
        <local:MultiSelectionTreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Pupils}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </local:MultiSelectionTreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:MultiSelectionTreeView>
```

Then I get an exception saying that I can't set the `Resource` twice. Even if I manage to set the style for the `TreeViewItem`s somehow, then the visual behaviour that I want for the `TreeViewItem`s is overwriten.

What I want to know is if there is some way to set a default visual behaviour for the `TreeViewItem`s I use in my `TreeView` user control and yet allow me to set an `Style` for those `TreeViewItem`s when I use the user control.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Exception message:

**System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:** ''Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '22' and line position '14'.'

Inner exception:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot re-initialize ResourceDictionary instance.

Comment: Can you paste the exception message?

Comment: My first guess is: The Resources of `<TreeView.Resources>` and `<local:MultiSelectionTreeView.Resources>` are the same and when you  put 2 different `Styles` without a unique identifier (like `x:Key`) who affect the same Element (`TreeViewItem`) in there, the compiler does not know which to take.

Comment: @Andy, my user control inherits from TreeView. What I want to achieve is to visually mark the selected items and still be able to set an style. For example, the typical TreeView allows to define an Style for the TreeViewItem and yet it shows the selected one. If I do it through attached behaviour I would face the same problem I think. I can't use a resource dictionary, because the control is going to be in a project and I want to use it in another project.

Comment: Put the resource dictionary and attached behaviour in a usercontrol library project. Reference and re-use wherever.

Comment: If you really wanted to be able to hand a style in you'd have to add a dependency property of some sort and add your style to the existing one in code. You can't have two resources like that and putting the style at some higher level would just mean the one in the control replaces it.

Comment: @Andy, I think I know what you mean, but in that case the responability of marking the selected items falls on the user of the component, because the style he/she defines must be based on the one I define in the resource dictionary and that's something I want to avoid.

Comment: @Andy, adding the user defined style to the defined one in the library seems like a promising solution. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy, that did the trick. Post an answer so I can mark it as the solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem is because you cannot have two resources sections for a control. They collide.

Since the idea is to expose the treeview itself as the control then you need some other way to pass in extra styling.
One way to do that is with a dependency property.
 Code in the control itself can then grab whatever you pass in and add it to the styling it already has. Not a very nice solution but it has the benefits of being reasonably straight forward without forcing you to redo the way the control works.